# Display Only 3 Languages in Google Translate HTML

Tags: javascript, html, translate

I am currently using Google Translate Script Code to convert the text into different languages in my website. 
However the languages dropdown has many options, I would like to have only 3 Languages ( Kannada, Hindi, English )

Here is the script which i am using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>


  function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
  }
```

Can anyone please tell me how do i have only Kannda,English and Hindi as Language Options

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you need to add includedLanguages  in the script 
like this :

```
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en' , includedLanguages : 'ar,xx,yy'}, 'google_translate_element');
  }
```

Comment: function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en',includedLanguages : 'kannada,hindi,english'}, 'google_translate_element');
      }

I added Like this, But still all the languages are showing up. Do i have to put up two initials that represents kannada hindi and english.? If yes, Where can i get those initials.?

Comment: don't use 'kannada,hindi,english' use their abbreviation. for example : for arabic : ar

Comment: Thank you! I got it.